# Azure B2C Registration campaign not working as expected

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

For our B2C Tennant we want to let our customers make use of the Microsoft Authenticator app. When doing research, we noticed that it was not possible to add the Authenticator App for existing users without disabling phone/text message authentication.
This is not an acceptable situation for us since that means that someone with customer credentials can take over the enrolment flow.

A MS engineer suggested the following:

> The desired situation should be possible with a “Registration
> campaign” -
> https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/AuthenticationMethodsMenuBlade/RegistrationCampaign
> Users will go through their regular sign-in, perform multifactor
> authentication as usual, and then be prompted to set up Microsoft
> Authenticator.

However, we enabled this option as described in the Documentation, but after an existing user signs in no Authenticator App Flow is started.

Does someone have experience how we can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

***As far as I know, even after enabling MFA if existing users don't receive authenticator app approval, please try below steps***:

- There is a chance of where your users selected “***Stay signed in***” while logging into their accounts. By doing this their devices will be treated as ***remembered device*** that suspends enabling MFA.
- While enabling MFA if you set ***Remember MFA on trusted device*** , then the user won't get prompts until the duration expires

[image]

- To resolve the issue, try clearing all old sessions history, by enabling ***“Revoke MFA sessions”***
- If the issue still persists, try enabling ***Re-register MFA***, that asks the users to set up a new MFA authentication method when they sign-in.

[image]

For more **reference**, please find the below links :

[Enable multifactor authentication in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

[Manage user authentication options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userdevicesettings#manage-user-authentication-options)